# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

I have an issue where I am receiving the error, "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  I have the `new` keyword in place.  I made sure the `ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable` existed.

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Imports Advance.Extensions.Reporting
    Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Imports Advance.Common.Reporting
    Imports System.IO

    Public Class Activity_EndAssignmentTool
        ReadOnly _dt As New DataTable
        Dim _dts As New DataTable
        Dim _bldts As New DataTable
        Dim _xml_file_name_creation As String
    '// This is the line that is causing the error ============
        ReadOnly _xml_datatable As ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable = New ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable()
    '//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   ====================================================================================== 

   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was caught
   HResult=-2146232828
   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly,        Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName)
   at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_Form.GetActivityForm(String className) in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Forms\Activity_Form.vb:line 126
   at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_Form.SetActivityClass() in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Forms\Activity_Form.vb:line 60
   InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
   HResult=-2147467261
   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Source=Advance.Extensions.Activities
   StackTrace:
   at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_EndAssignmentTool.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Activity_Forms\Activity_EndAssignmentTool.Designer.vb:line 479
   at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_EndAssignmentTool..ctor() in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Activity_Forms\Activity_EndAssignmentTool.vb:line 12
   InnerException:
```

Can someone name some other reasons why I could be getting this error?  I have looked at multiple links but a lot of the answers don't apply in my situation.

["Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error (mscorlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648113/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-error-mscorlib)

FYI I have tried `ReadOnly _xml_datatable as New ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndASsignmentDataTable()` and there was still an issue.

Any help is appreciated.  Let me know if there is any other information you need.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having this issue when I start the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @marcelomiorelli I didn't have the issue with ssms, but I found this forum that might help you.  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/668421/denali-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-during-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized object properly. Here...

```
ReadOnly _xml_datatable As ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable = New ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable()
```

Should be

```
Private ReadOnly _xml_datatable As New ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable()
```

Your real issue is

```
 InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
 HResult=-2147467261
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Source=Advance.Extensions.Activities
```

You need to look into constructor of `COATSEndAssignmentDataTable`. you have `NullReferenceException` in there. These two lines tell you exact location

```
at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_EndAssignmentTool.InitializeComponent()
in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Activity_Forms\Activity_EndAssignmentTool.Designer.vb:line 479

at Advance.Extensions.Activities.Activity_EndAssignmentTool..ctor() 
in C:\Users\JJanssen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Legacy\Advance Extensions\advance.extensions.activities\Activity_Forms\Activity_EndAssignmentTool.vb:line 12
```

Comment: Whether I put Private or not, this change still does not work properly.  I still receive the same error.

Comment: `Private ReadOnly _xml_datatable As New ReportsData_Employee.COATSEndAssignmentDataTable()` still produces the same error.

Comment: @JohnJanssen You need to look into constructor of `COATSEndAssignmentDataTable`. you have `NullReferenceException` in there

Comment: Very interesting.  A `.EndInit()` in my designer that has been there for many years, threw the exception.  Thank you for analyzing the stacktrace.

Comment: @JohnJanssen No problem. I hope you resolve it soon.