# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

I am trying to automate a reactjs application and the framework our project is using built on C# and protractor-net.

After any click or assert function I get the following error, but the defined action in the code executes successfully.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : timeout
```

What is the cause of this error?

```
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
    using Protractor;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public Class personalinformations
    {

    private NgWebDriver _ngdriver;


            public PersonalInformations(IWebDriver driver)
            {

                _ngdriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
                PageFactory.InitElements(_ngdriver, this);
                _ngdriver.IgnoreSynchronization = true;

            }

     [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "btnSubmit")]
            private IWebElement btnsave { get; set; }

     public void saveSection()
            {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ngdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));         
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*@id='btnSubmit']"));

btnsave.Click();
    }
}
```

Note: While using  Thread.Sleep(1000) for wait sometimes the code works.Also I tried with Javascript to click the element the result is same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Code trials please

Comment: updated the code please

Answer (score 2):

Once you wait for the element through *WebDriverWait* and *ExpectedConditions* method *ElementIsVisible* as in the next step you are invoking `Click()` so instead of *ElementIsVisible* method you need to invoke [ElementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) method as follows :

```
public void saveSection()
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ngdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));         
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*@id='btnSubmit']"));
    btnsave.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a funny Exception: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.";
i met this for several times, but i searched this post ["Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error (mscorlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648113/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-error-mscorlib)
they said that you should check the root cause of this Exception behind.
so i added a

try {element.Click();} catch(Exception e){Console.WriteLine(e);}

then the exception seems escaped away...