# C# to move files older than N days from one folder to another folder

Tags: c#

I'm new to world of C#. What I'm trying to do is move files older than N days from one folder to another folder. This to archive files continuously. When used within SSIS package, I get error saying, "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.".

Details of error:

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript() "
Any thoughts ?

***Code:***

```
      public partial class Script Main : 
      Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    string rootFolderPath = @"\\A\B";
    string destinationPath = @"\\A\C";

    public void Main()
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath); ;

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                if (File.GetCreationTime(file)
                    < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                {
                    File.Move(rootFolderPath, destinationPath);
                }
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: Any other error details, such as an Inner Exception? The error message that you posted just says "an error happened", which by itself isn't too helpful.

Comment: General advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/648123/1043380

Comment: You have to specify the file name in the File.Move, like `File.Move(file, Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(file)));`

Comment: Klaus Gütter -Thank you ! That seem to do the trick !

Comment: look too the Authorization right about your folder.