# Converting white pixel to any over color with aforge/setpixel

Tags: vb.net, aforge

i have the following code in vb.net to convert a single pixel to any other color. The chosen parameter inside of setpixel are for test purposes.

`InvoiceImage.SetPixel(0 , 0, color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30))`

But i get the following error: *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*
Why is that?

Comment: 1) Make sure you have enabled [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project. (And make it the default for new VB projects.)

Comment: 2)  Does anything in ["Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error (mscorlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648113/1115360) help?

Answer (score 0):

cloning the bitmap one more time and executing SetPixel on this copy worked ;)